# MySql Count on each field

Tags: mysql

i have a problem with Query . will anybody help me out please

Let us conside a table like this. **we will store 0 for no and 1 for yes** . For Some tables we used 1 for yes and 2 for no .  Each month we will send a survey Question to our client which they will tick yes or no

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id| Month | Customer | QuestionA | QuestionB | QuestionC | QuestionD |
+---+-------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 1 | Jan   |  1100    |  1        |   0       |    1      |  0        |
| 2 | Jan   |  1101    |  0        |   0       |    1      |  1        |
| 3 | Jan   |  1102    |  1        |   1       |    1      |  1        |
| 4 | Feb   |  1100    |  1        |   1       |    0      |  1        |
| 5 | Mar   |  1100    |  1        |   1       |    0      |  0        |
+---+-------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

how can i write a query which will show how many ticked yes for each question . in other words for jan i need to get like

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Month | Customer | QuestionA | QuestionB | QuestionC | QuestionD |
+-------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Jan   |  1100    |  2        |   1       |    3      |  2        |
+-------+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

ie QuestionA was ticked by 2 clients and Questionb by 1 so on...

**EDIT:**

But in some table we have used 1 for yes and 2 for no . what to do with that. im sorry we have designed like that and it is being used for more than 3 years. so they wont allow me to change 0 for no and 1 for yes

Comment: what have you tried? Look into `GROUP BY` and `SUM()` in the [man](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html).

Comment: now im using a query for each count like select count(QuestionA) from tblsurvery where QuestionA=1 and month = 'Jan' .

Comment: Why did you keep the customer field in your result ?

Comment: `thanks but in some table we have used 1 for yes and 2 for no` that should have been part of the question not comments on answers...

Comment: @Fabin , we added customer just to know the customer taste at teh end of each year and serve him based on that

Comment: But in your example, adding the customer field make no sense cause customer 1100 answer only 1 time in January...

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested but you can try this. Tell me the result so we can update if necessary.

```
select month, sum(QuestionA), sum(QuestionB), sum(QuestionC), sum(QuestionD) from table_name where month='Jan'
```

Comment: thanks but in some table we have used 1 for yes and 2 for no . what to do with that. im sorry we have designed like that and it is being used for more than 3 years. so they wont allow me to change 0 for no and 1 for yes .

Answer (score 0):

This should work, you need to see what would happen though if you don't have a year field and next January rolls around... you need a year field also so you can group by month and year

```
SELECT
  `Month`,
  SUM(`QuestionA`) AS `QuestionA`,
  SUM(`QuestionB`) AS `QuestionB`,
  SUM(`QuestionC`) AS `QuestionC`,
  SUM(`QuestionD`) AS `QuestionD`
FROM
  tblsurvery
GROUP BY
  `Month`
```

**EDIT:**

**`thanks but in some table we have used 1 for yes and 2 for no`**

```
SELECT
  `Month`,
  SUM(IF(`QuestionA`=1,1,0) AS `QuestionA`,
  SUM(IF(`QuestionB`=1,1,0) AS `QuestionB`,
  SUM(IF(`QuestionC`=1,1,0) AS `QuestionC`,
  SUM(IF(`QuestionD`=1,1,0) AS `QuestionD`
FROM
  tblsurvery
GROUP BY
  `Month`
```

Comment: thanks but in some table we have used 1 for yes and 2 for no . what to do with that. im sorry we have designed like that and it is being used for more than 3 years. so they wont allow me to change 0 for no and 1 for yes . Sorry for that. here is the real problem for me. some time if they didnt save anything it will be null values

Comment: @SindhuVinodhini please see my edit or nosid answer with edit above for the right answer. And please next time include information like you commented in your actual question.

Answer (score 0):

If customer field is not needed (that what I suspected), you can try this :

```
SELECT
    month,
    SUM(IF(QuestionA=1,1,0)) AS QuestionA,
    SUM(IF(QuestionB=1,1,0)) AS QuestionB,
    SUM(IF(QuestionC=1,1,0)) AS QuestionC,
    SUM(IF(QuestionD=1,1,0)) AS QuestionD
FROM survey
GROUP BY month;
```

See SQLFIDDLE : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19a56/3/0

If you need it, try this :

```
SELECT
    month, min(customer),
    SUM(IF(QuestionA=1,1,0)) AS QuestionA,
    SUM(IF(QuestionB=1,1,0)) AS QuestionB,
    SUM(IF(QuestionC=1,1,0)) AS QuestionC,
    SUM(IF(QuestionD=1,1,0)) AS QuestionD
FROM survey
GROUP BY month;
```

See SQLFIDDLE : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19a56/6/0